# I can only read one class

Tags: c#, edi.net

I am trying to read an EDI file using Edi.net

But I hit a problem when I want to read the next class.

this is a snippet of my file (I splitted into separate lines here, the actual file is just one long line)

```
UNB+UNOA:1+0935HRB2001101+MOL4267HUBUD00+100930:1549+00000000008914
'UNH+1+LOGMES:1:0:GM
'BGM+992:Z01:ZGM
'DTM+243:1009301549:201
'NAD+MS+GM*DRIVE
'NAD+MR+MOL42670HUBUD00
'SEQ++XXXXXX
'DTM+11:1008291900:201
'DTM+191:100930:101
'TDT+20++00+:::HOEGH TRADER++00000000
'LOC+Z03+KRDAT10
'LOC+8+HUBUD00
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a class Heading, and this class will contain other classes called `UNB`, `UNH`, `BGM`, `DTM`, and so on

so it looks like this

[image]

Notice that class `UNB` is populated, but class `UNH` is NULL

How should I design my classes so both `UNB` and `UNH` will be filled. And off course also `BGM`, `DTM`, `NAD`, and so on...

I found [this answer](https://www.qdxingtu.com/key/EdiSegmentGroup%20not%20parsing%20the%20whole%20Segment.html) and I tried it, but it did not solve my problem.

This is the code I used

```
public class Interchange
{
    public HeadingSection HeadingSection { get; set; }
    public Quote QuoteMessage { get; set; }
}

[EdiMessage]
public class Quote
{
    public List<VehicleRecord> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

[EdiElement, EdiPath("UNB/*")]
public class HeadingUNB
{
    [EdiValue("X(4)", Mandatory = true, Path = "UNB/0", Description = "Syntax Identifier")]
    public string SyntaxIdentifier { get; set; }

    [EdiValue("9(1)", Path = "UNB/0/1", Mandatory = true)]
    public int SyntaxVersion { get; set; }

    [EdiValue("X(35)", Mandatory = true, Path = "UNB/1")]
    public string SenderIdentificationCode { get; set; }

    [EdiValue("X(35)", Path = "UNB/2/0", Mandatory = true)]
    public string RecipientIdentificationCode { get; set; }

    [EdiValue("9(6)", Path = "UNB/3/0", Format = "ddMMyy", Description = "Shipment Date")]
    [EdiValue("9(4)", Path = "UNB/3/1", Format = "HHmm", Description = "Shipment Time")]
    public DateTime Shipment_Preparation_Date { get; set; }

    [EdiValue("X(14)", Path = "UNB/4/0", Mandatory = true)]
    public string InterchangeControlRef { get; set; }
}

[EdiElement, EdiPath("UNH/*")]
public class HeadingUNH
{
    [EdiValue("X(14)", Mandatory = true, Path = "UNH/0", Description = "Message Reference Number")]
    public string MessageReferenceNumber { get; set; }
}

[EdiSegment, EdiSegmentGroup("UNB", SequenceEnd = "GIN")]
public class HeadingSection
{
    public HeadingUNB UNB { get; set; }
    public HeadingUNH UNH { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with EDI.net but the file you shared should have ' at end of line instead of at start of line

Comment: It is not the complete file, just a snippet. As I mentioned in the question, I have splitted it here for better readability. The actual file is one long text.

Comment: Try changing X(1) instead of X(14) for HeadingUNH

[EdiElement, EdiPath("UNH/*")]
public class HeadingUNH
{
    [EdiValue("X(14)", Mandatory = true, Path = "UNH/0", Description = "Message Reference Number")]
    public string MessageReferenceNumber { get; set; }
}

Comment: It makes no difference. The problem is that `EDi.net` seems to skip everything after UNB until GIN. The GIN part can be read but only if I do it outside the headingUNB

Comment: I am trying to help you out. Please bear with me if making any vague solution :-) i think UNH should be child of UNB, if yes then remove public HeadingUNH UNH { get; set; } from HeadingSection class and move this property under HeadingUNB

Comment: Do not understand me wrong, I do appreciate your help. I do not want to make UNH a child of UNB. I want both to be child of headerSection. But it seems I can only make one of them child of headerSection. So I am hoping on someone with lots of `edi.net`experience to read this and help me out